# Can tooltip text be consistent when hovering over a comment labels?

Tags: discussion, bug, comments, tooltips

Look at the following labels:

[image: OMG]

- "this comment adds something useful to the post"
- "this comment was edited 1 time"
- "Flag this comment for serious problems or moderator attention"

Is there a reason for capitalizing only the "flag" action?
I know I might be a bit petty, but can we please capitalize the first two labels or decapitalize the last one?

Answer (score 18):

This definitely seems like a mistake to me. The buttons under a post also have a similar problem:

- share - "short permalink to this question"
- edit - "Suggested edits are not allowed on non-tag-wiki posts on meta sites."
- flag - "flag this post for serious problems or moderator attention"

Also, tooltip for "edit" button has a period, while others do not.

Comment: What are the three most important things in copy-editing? 1.) Consistency, b) Consistency III. consistency.